# Haar Normalization

Tags: signal-processing, image-processing, wavelets

In the pseudo code of haar transfom provided by [Wavelets for Computer Graphics](https://grail.cs.washington.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/stollnitz-1995-wfc1.pdf). Before implementing the decomposition step, we need to divide the coefficients C by $\sqrt{h}$ for normalization. Can anyone explain why we need this step and how can it normalize our coefficients.

Thanks.

[pseudo-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm0CT.png)